# Use PHP/DOM to delete "Nth" li element?

Tags: php, parsing, dom

I have an HTML form (form.html) communicating with a php file (action.php). The input from the form adds an li element to the top of a separate, static HTML file (content.html). However, I also want to delete the last li element in content.html. It seems there is a better, more reliable way than regex, so I've been attempting DOM parsing. Is there a way to delete the last li element in content.html using PHP and DOM?

HTML (form.html):

```
<form action="action.php" method="post">
  Year: <input type="text" name="year" size="3" /><br />
  URL: <input type="text" name="url" size="3" /><br />
  Description: <input type="text" name="description" size="3" /><br />
  <input type="submit" name="preview" value="Preview" /> 
  <input type="submit" name="update" value="Update" />
</form>
```

PHP (action.php):

```
else if ($_POST['update']) {

$item = <<<MYTAG

  <li><h2><a href="$url">$year</a></h2><span class="desctext">$description</span></li>

MYTAG;

$doc = new DOMDocument;
$doc->load('content.html');

$file = $doc->documentElement;

$removethis = $file->getElementsByTagName("li")->item(0);
$old = $file->removeChild($removethis);

echo $doc->saveXML();

$file_data = "$item\n";
$file_data .= file_get_contents('file.html');
file_put_contents('file.html', $file_data);

    }
```

Comment: And what exactly is the problem you're looking for an answer for?

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear (I updated my first post). Is there a way to use PHP and DOM to delete the last element from an HTML file? Thank you.

Comment: just a note, XML parsing is not good for HTML parsing, try using http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/ - you can use css selectors with this lib.

Comment: @steve `DOMDocument` could also handle HTML: `$dom = new DOMDocument(); $dom->loadHTMLFile( $url ); $dom->saveHTMLFile( $fileName );`; it's also useful to suppress DOMDocument parsing errors on HTML5-elements: `libxml_use_internal_errors( true );`

Comment: oops, didn't know! thanks! the css selector thing in simplehtmldom is still neat, though ;)

Comment: Thanks for the responses. Basically, I want to delete the 6th iteration of the li element. Is there any way to do this?